# How to fix the need to use sudo before starting Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I have no clue why but I seem to need to use 'sudo mrt' everytime I start meteor. I also need to use sudo when installing mrt packages otherwise I get permission denied errors.

I inspected the folder on my Mac and it seems I have full read & write permission.

I even tried this command

```
sudo chown -Rv [username] [directory]
```

And still no luck, I need to keep using sudo for everything Meteor.

How can I take full ownership of the folder and not have to use sudo anymore when doing anything with meteor?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you installed meteorite as a local node module (this create a node_modules directory in the folder you typed the install command).

You need to install mrt globally using this command :

```
sudo npm install -g meteorite
```

This will install mrt for all users on your system and then you won't need sudo to run mrt.

You can also try to reset the ownership of the meteor folder (I had an issue with this one time).

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.meteor
```

If you're out of luck, try to uninstall both mrt and meteor to start from scratch and detect procedurally where your problem is.

Comment: hmm that command didn't work for me, but I just tried this on the hidden meteor folder and it worked: sudo chown -Rv [username] [hidden .meteor directory location]